# How to speed up mariaDB query using multiple db server, using Galera Cluster and MaxScale?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera, maxscale

I test with stress test tool (to run many concurrent user and many query). There is no speed added when i use more db server (i use 5 servers).

I have check on each server, and i see the queries have been distributed on each server.

What should i do, if i want to scale-up the database server, to add more speed on queries?

Answer (score 1):

Galera maxes out at somewhere around 5 nodes in the cluster.  Probably it is due to the broadcasting of each write to every other node, and waiting for replies.

There are many ways to scale up a MySQL; Galera is one of them, and it is perhaps the best *today* for *write* scaling.

For *read* scaling, replication slaves provide virtually unlimited scaling.  You can hang traditional replication slaves off of each Galera node.  This will let you offload the reads from your 5 nodes.  Slaves can be cascaded (using "relays"), thereby giving unlimited scaling.  A server can easily have 10 slaves hanging off it; do 6 levels of that, and you have a million servers.  (I have not worked with more than 3 levels and 30+ slaves.)

A common way of scaling up is to look at the code.  [*Composite indexes*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) is unknown to a lot of novices.  For inserting, batching and `LOAD DATA` is very effective.  For Data Warehousing, [*Summary tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) can often speed up "reports" 10-fold.  For high speed ingestion, [*ping-ponging a staging table*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/) is very good.  For GUID/UUID indexes, [*abandoning*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/) them is best.  Ditto for [*EAV*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/entity-attribute-value-implementation/).  For huge deletes there are [*several approaches*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/big-deletes/).

And [*my tips on Galera*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tips-on-converting-to-galera/).

Comment: Thank you, how about this statement "perhaps the best today for write scaling.", i have test with heavy insert queries, but there is no improve when i add nodes.

Comment: Single-row inserts?  Batched?  Using auto-increment?  Etc.  Please describe your "heavy insert queries"; there may be ways to improve the performance.